# \n doesn't seem to work in IE

Tags: jquery, json

Here is how it looks in IE

```
I replied back ______________________________ I replied to you 
______________________________ MonList
```

Here is how it looks in FF:

```
I replied back


______________________________

I replied to you


______________________________

MonList
```

Here is the JSON that is sent back in the response that FF and IE use:

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe (3)",
            "subject": "RE: RE: MonList",
            "message": "I replied back\n\n\n______________________________\n\nI replied to you\n\n\n______________________________\n\nMonList",
            "date": "3/19/2012 4:28:37 PM",
            "senttotal": "Distributor (1)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to do something different to have IE treat \n the same was as FF?

Here is the code that grabs the information from the database and puts it into the JSON:

Specifically the m.Message

```
sql = ""
    sql = sql & " SET NOCOUNT ON"
    sql = sql & " SELECT m.ID, m.DistID, m.StatusID, m.Subject, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(m.Message, CHAR(10), '\n'), CHAR(13), '\n'), CHAR(9), '') AS Message, m.CreatedDate, m.SentTotal, d.FName + ' ' + d.LName AS Name"
    sql = sql & " FROM message m"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Distributor d ON m.DistID = d.DistID"
    sql = sql & " WHERE m.ID = " & CInt(request("messageid"))
```

Comment: no browser will render newlines unless it is within a `<pre>` block

Comment: Well FF is.  I will add that and hope that IE will then respect the newlines as well.

Comment: What you need is to tell us what is the code that tranforms this JSON to the HTML.

Comment: In Windows you usually need to do `\n\r` but doubt this will help.

Comment: newlines are whitespace as far as HTML is concerned, and whitespace is eaten and compressed into one space. Nothing new or unusual about this.

Comment: It does not for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6B46F/ But that might depend on the MIME type of the response.... these kind of line breaks have no meaning in HTML.

Comment: @elclanrs \n\r worked.  Thank you for that suggestion.  If you post it as the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows you usually need to do `\n\r`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `<br />` to do the line break.

Comment: Actually it was an awesome answer without the fix ;)

Comment: @simonwang  This I'm sure would have fixed it, the only issue was one of the items I was populating was a `<textarea></textarea>` which would just print out the `<br />`.  This was my fault for not explaining both situations in which I used the JSON.